# What is wrong with my code. I am using python to try to data scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to print the first thirty picks in the nba draft. I am using the page: http://nbadraft.net/2012mock_draft for information.  Right when it runs it says:

```
invalid syntax: python1.py, line 8, pos 28
File "/Users/seanyeh/Downloads/python1.py", line 8, in ?
  patFinderLink = re.compile(‘<link rel.*href=”(.*)” />’)
```

So this is my code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# or if your're using BeautifulSoup4:
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://nbadraft.net/2012mock_draft').read())

patFinderLink = re.compile(‘<link rel.*href=”(.*)” />’)

findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink,webpage)

listIterator = []
listIterator[:] = range(1,30)

for i in listIterator:
    print findPatLink[i]
```

Comment: Repeat after me: Don't use regex to parse Html, don't use regex to parse Html, don't use..
No really, don't do that - there are libraries for it.

Comment: If you are intending to republish this information, you _might_ need permission from the site you scraped it from. May be worth checking before you put a lot of effort into this project!

Comment: Use [pyquery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)

Answer (score 3):

You have some funny characters on this line (perhaps this is due to cut-and-paste?)

```
 ‘<link rel.*href=”(.*)” />’)
```

also, I believe you are missing

```
 import re
```

in your code. I also get an error that `webpage` isn't defined.

Since you are using BeautifulSoup, why not  use *it* to extract the elements you are interested in? The whole idea with BeautifulSoup is to avoid "manual" parsing using string ops or regular expressions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure the problem is the curly quotes in the regex, and also fully agree that the regex is not the way to go in the first place.